# truffle init webpack on Heroku

Tags: web3js, truffle, metamask

I'm having a hard time exporting the Truffle sample app on Heroku. I'd like to use it with Metamask.
I tried simply pushing the code from my local machine (where the code is working) adding the following Procfile:

```
web: npm run dev
```

But to no avail, it's not working on Heroku.
Any advices?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to deploy it specifying `devServer` in `webpack.config.js`:

```
devServer: {
    port: process.env.PORT || 8080,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    disableHostCheck: true
},
```

As a side note, I had to downgrade `npm` from `5.3.0` to `5.2.x` due to this issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17858